# Magento dynamic message in email

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have the functionality where i have to send the email to two different email ids with different message content. 
The problem is that the same message content gets sent to both the ids.
Any one's help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done through a little custom programming / custom module (as i 've already done this in a project some months back).

1. At first create two new Email Templates under your System->transactional emails Lets say email_template1 and email_template2, if you would like to manage your content from the admin panel or else as an ugly way you can also hard code your email content in your custom module helper or Model class. I prefer the first one.
2. Then Load the Email template by its code.Load it based on your condition if the recepient email is XXXX@YYY.com then load template 1 else load template2

   ```
   $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->loadByCode('email_template1');
   ```
3. Set the sender Names and emails

   ```
   $emailTemplate
               ->setSenderName($sender_name)
               ->setSenderEmail($sender_email)
               ->setTemplateCode('email_template1')->save();
   ```
4. Then set the custom variables if any and send it to the recepeints

   ```
   $processedTemplate = $emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($emailTemplateVariables); 

       if($emailTemplate->isValidForSend()){
           /* Send the email */
                          $emailTemplate->send($recepient_email,$recepient_name,$processedTemplate);               
      }
   ```

   Quite simple right. In this way you can achieve what you have asked.

Comment: Thanx a ton Haijerome for your help. I am working on the same. Will let you know soon..